# Laravel 5.5 Method Links does not exist (Pagination) when applied to user model

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, pagination

I am trying to figure out why my pagination stops working as soon as I apply it to a user model. Here is the scenario: I am making a website which is a note takes, a user can take notes save them and all that. On a page /notes all notes made can be seen used for me to see weather each user is able to save notes. Pagination works there without a problem. Once I made a user Dashboard and I show notes they made with their user id I get this error:

> Method links does not exist 
>   …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php
>   96

I have no clue why this is happening. When I delete the code from view: {{$notebooks->links()}} - the error goes away and so does pagination. The moment I put it in the error happens all over again.

Here is the code from my view and controllers.

DashboardController:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $notebooks = DB::table('notebooks', $user->notebooks)->paginate(4);
        return view('dashboard')->with('notebooks', $user->notebooks);
    }
}
```

Dashboard View (with paginate links code):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

       <!-- Main component for call to action -->
       <div class="container text-center">
           <!-- heading -->
           <h1 class="pull-xs-left">Your Dashboard</h1>
           <br>
           <div class="pull-xs-right">
               <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/notebook/create" role="button"> New Note +</a>
           </div>
            <div class="pull-xs-right">
               <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/contacts/create" role="button"> New Contact +</a>
           </div>
           <div class="pull-xs-right">
   <!--the dropdown menu -->
                   <div class="dropdown show">
                           <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Sort Notebooks By
                           </a>

                           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{action('NotesController@ascendingId')}}">Note Number A - Z</a>
                             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{action('NotesController@descendingId')}}">Note Number Z - A</a>
                             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{action('NotesController@descendingTime')}}">Latest Time Posted</a>
                             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{action('NotesController@ascendingTime')}}">Oldest Time Posted</a>

                           </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

           <div class="clearfix">
           </div>
           <br>

       @if(count($notebooks) > 0)
           @foreach ($notebooks as $notebook)
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                   <div class="card" style="width: 26rem;">
                    <div class="card-header" >
                           Client: {{$notebook->client_name}}
                       </div>
                       <div class="card-block" >
                           <h4 class="card-title " style="height: 5rem;"><strong><a href="/notebook/{{$notebook->id}}" >{{$notebook->name}}</a></strong></h4>
                           <p class="card-text"  style="height: 7rem;">{{$notebook->note_description}}</p>
                       </div>
                       <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                           <li class="list-group-item"><b>Last Updated:</b> {{$notebook->updated_at->format('d-m-Y')}}</li>
                           <li class="list-group-item"> 
                               <a href="/notebook/{{$notebook->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-info">Edit Note</a>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="card-block">
                     {!!Form::open(['action' =>  ['NotesController@destroy', $notebook->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
                           {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                           {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
                     {!!Form::close()!!}
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
           @endforeach

</div>
<!-- /container -->
           <hr>
            <div class="container text-center">
                    {{$notebooks->links()}}
                  </div>
           </div>
           @else
           <div>
               <div class="col-lg-12 no-notes">
                   <p>No notes found, go ahead and make your first note! :)</p>
                   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/notebook/create" role="button"> Make My First Note</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       @endif


@endsection
```

Just a reminder this works perfectly without the user model. I am lost as how to fit it. Using Laravel 5.5.26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
$notebooks = auth()->user()->notebooks()->paginate(4);
return view('dashboard')->with('notebooks', $notebooks);
```

Also, you do not need to get a user from DB since you can access `auth()->user()` instance in a view.

Comment: Thanks, but now that I done this it tells me: "Method paginate does not exist." :( Any idea why pagination seems not to exist? It has before the user authentication.

Comment: @MonikaZygadlo I assumed that you've defined the `notebooks` relationship since you're trying to use it. If you didn't define it, do this. If you want help with this too, please tell me what foreign key are you using to tie these tables.

Comment: in my Notebook.php i have a relationship:    public function user(){
          return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); //relationship of post to a user
      } and in my User.php I have: public function notebooks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Notebook'); //a user can have a lot of posts 1 to many relationship
    } I have done this by following a youtube tutorial. So this listen all of my notebooks perfectly but once i try use pagination it just breaks as if pagination does not exist :/

Comment: @MonikaZygadlo what does `dd(auth()->user()->notebooks);` show?

Comment: It lists all of my notebooks for that user with the user id so it shows 5 of them, I would like it to be 4 per row then paginate. I m sorry to be wasting your time but I have spend 2 days looking for a solution and I can't seem to solve it :(

Comment: @MonikaZygadlo no problem. You need to change `->notebooks->` to `->notebooks()->`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: OH MY GOD!! Thank you so so much! This has solved it, it paginates now! I would have never figured that out myself I am quite new to laravel. Thank you again!

Comment: Just one more question can I add order by inside that somehow?

Comment: @MonikaZygadlo I can't answer the question because you haven't shown any code, tables structure etc. It depends on what table structure do you have and what exactly you want to accomplish. It's a good idea to try it by yourself (read about the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) first). If you'll not be able to accomplish this, create a new question, post the code and relationships you defined and other useful information.

Comment: I actually added it and its like this:   $notebooks = auth()->user()->notebooks()->orderBy('created_at','des')->paginate(4); So thank you anyway! Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @MonikaZygadlo oh, I thought you're talking about orders like "order a notebook in our shop" (where `Order` is a different model etc). Sorry. BTW, you also can use a readable shortcut for `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` which is `->latest()`